# Trans2Pay integration in Asp.net mvc4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, payment-gateway

I am new in asp.net mvc4 and i have to integrate trans2pay in asp.net(C#) mvc4 application. I searched about this from google but i couldn't found any solution to integrate it. Please tell me about any blog, api or source code for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found trans2pay webservice for trans2pay processing but not find its documentation, Please tell me if any one know abot documentation and also tell me that how to add this webservice in visual stdio